# STRING_SPLIT in Azure Synapse Analytics

Tags: azure-synapse

Is `STRING_SPLIT` supported in Azure Synapse's T-SQL? If so, how to use it in a pre-existing SQL Pool?

I'm doing this

```
select STRING_SPLIT('one,two,three',',')
```

and getting this as a result

```
'STRING_SPLIT' is not a recognized built-in function name.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Anders, it is available:

```
select value from string_split ('one,two,three',',')
```

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=azure-sqldw-latest)

Comment: ah! I was using the function wrong. follow up -- how might i return just `'one'`, or better yet -- how might I use `string_split` to map a column with two commas into three?

Comment: Return 'one': select top 1 * from (select value from string_split ('one,two,three',',')) a

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean by 'map a column with two commas into three' ? Sorry, my brain is a bit slow today.

Comment: thanks for the help! I broke this question into its post.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64691302/azure-synapse-turn-an-n-length-delimited-list-column-into-n-distinct-columns