# Azure Synapse: turn an n-length, delimited list column into n distinct columns

Tags: azure-synapse

In Azure Synapse, I'd like to convert this table

```
id,list
0,'a:b'
1,'d:e'
2,'g:h'
```

into this one

```
id,col1,col2
0,a,b
1,d,e
2,g,h
```

I'm sure `STRING_SPLIT` comes into play, but it's return format confuses me.

Comment: I don't think string_split() is the answer to this problem, as it returns multiple rows per string. Do you always have a string with two delimited parts? If so, use a combination of charindex() to find the delimiter, then two substrings around the delimiter to separate the columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data is as simple as shown then something like this will work:

```
;WITH cte AS (
SELECT *, CHARINDEX( ':', list ) AS xpos
FROM dbo.rawData 
)
SELECT id, LEFT( list, xpos - 1 ) AS col1, SUBSTRING ( list, xpos + 1, 50 ) AS col2
FROM cte
```

If your data has the single quotes then use `REPLACE` function to clean them.  If this does not work for you, please provide some more realistic sample data.